# how to load balance jboss4.2.2AS on amazon ec2 with distributed caching

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, distributed-caching, jboss-cache

I have an old application which is hard to upgrade to a newer version of jboss. I want to keep the jboss version same(to 4.2.2 AS) and load balance it on amazon EC2 with distributed caching.

I am able to load balance it, but I am struggling with distributed caching. Can anyone please help me with this?

For caching I am using the following libraries:
 `org.hibrnate.cacheable` and `org.jbosss.cache`.

Is it possible to implement distributed caching on jboss4.2.2 with these libraries? If yes, then how should I go about it?